# Pass the current querystring parameters through symfony forms

Tags: forms, symfony

Our application uses several webforms and some of them only should add or change several parameters in the querystring. As example there are a filter form and a form for the list order (just a dropdown).

Both are indipendant, but if I change one, I have to pass the current querystring parameters with the new request. How can I manage it?

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the possible solutions, it will depend on your implementation if it would help you.

```php
<?php
$allowedQueryParams = array('param1', 'param2', 'param3');
// I'll fake a request here
$request = new Request(array('param2' => 'foo', 'param3' => 'bar', 'param4' => 'dummy'));

$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()->getFormFactory();

$formBuilder = $formFactory->createBuilder();
$formBuilder->add('param1', 'text');

$data = array();
foreach ($allowedQueryParams as $param) {
    if ($request->query->has($param)) {
        // Add the query param as hidden field to you form
        $formBuilder->add($param, 'hidden');
        $data[$param] = $request->query->get($param);
    }
}

$formBuilder->setData($data);

$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
```

So basically you add hidden fields with the current query parameters.

Edit: 
But if you would have many forms, you might want to do this with an [EventSubscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Comment: Its not so easy, because the formclass has to add all these fields. The form can be included in several pages in combination with other requests. Another point is, that the symfony forms often uses arrays and these structure must be remain thru hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to combine the two forms into one master form.

From your controller:

```
$formData = array(
    'filterParams'    => array(), // Default filter parameters
    'listOrderParams' => array(), // Default list order parameters
);
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    ->add('filterParams',    new FilterFormType())
    ->add('listOrderParams', new ListOrderFormType())
    ->add('update', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {

    $formData = $form->getData();
```

Comment: Probably is could be the best way to archive this aim. I'll try it.

Comment: But this is not fetching data from query-string isnit?